# HTML5 : how to load an image onClick in a specific place

Tags: javascript, css, xml, html

Hy all;
I am using Javascript and HTML5 with XML.
The Javascript will read data from the XML file to get the name of the image and it works smoothly.
In a right menu tab, i have put the following code:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="loadImg(1)">Part 1</a></li>
```

Now i have created the function loadImg as following :

```
function loadImg(n){
TestP[n] = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
var img = document.createElement('img');
alert(TestP[n]);
img.src = TestP[n];   
alert(n);
alert(TestP[n]);
document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

I just want that the created image will take place in the right part, note that i am using the following CSS:

```
#container {
 width:800px;
 }
#left {
    top:10%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    left:3%;
   }
#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 30%;
}
```

I wish that when i click, the image will be created in the right position, Any ideas???

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById('right').appendChild(img)` instead of `document.body.appendChild(img)`?

Comment: It Workd :D thank you :) please post your comment as an answer so that i could mark it right :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append an element to a specific container use `document.getElementById('yourID') .appendChild(yourElement)` instead of `document.body.appendChild(yourElement)`. This will add your element as a child to the element with the ID `yourID`.

Comment: IT worked Thanks!! but there's a small bug..If i click twice , i want that the next picture will load in the exact same place, but instead all the body will change..any ideas?

Comment: @ELiasRahme: `.appendChild` will append another child/img. So for every click a new `<img>` is going to be added to `#right`. To prevent this you could save `var img = null` outside of `loadImg` and check if it's `null`. If it's null, then create a new image, and if it's already defined just change the src. There are several ways to accomplish this, this is just off the top of my head.